# Qual a maneira correta de colocar o endereço dentro do Path?

Tags: android

Porque não estou conseguindo localizar o meu arquivo.txt. Segue o código:

```
public void criatxt() {

    String texto = "XXX";

    try {
        String filePath = this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString()
                + "/meuarquivo.txt";
        File f = new File(filePath);
        PrintWriter arq = new PrintWriter(f);
        System.out.println("Salvou");
        arq.print(texto);
        arq.close();
    } catch (Exception er) {
        er.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Salvou: " + er.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Gravando nessa pasta você não vai conseguir ver ele mesmo, essa pasta só é acessível pelo próprio aplicativo. Experimente gravar numa pasta pública (internal storage) ou no cartão de memória (external storage). Depois elaboro uma resposta, enquanto isso veja: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220476/android-write-to-internal-storage

Comment: vlw cara, percebi que esse meu código gravava no data/data do Android e acabei pegando de lá mesmo, mas fica o aprendizado para quando não tiver acesso ao data, quanto estiver usando o celular como device. vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Para pegar o caminho da pasta de download do android, assim ficará fácil de você encontrar seus arquivos salvos.